# What are the consequences of declaring an object as "new" multiple times?

Tags: c#, android, object, xna

I am making a game in C# and XNA that will be targeted toward mobile devices like Android and Windows Phone 7, 7.1, 8. It will use an object called Minigame that determines the current game that the player will be playing (one minigame is set on a farm, another is set in a city, etc). The code for creating a minigame is set up like this.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    //This is a global variable
    Minigame minigame;

    ...

    //This method loads the minigame when the player chooses one from the main menu
    //It is loaded using an instance of a class that inherits from the Minigame class
    void LoadMinigame(int number)
    {
        if (number == 0)
        {
            minigame = new MinigameOne();
        }
        else if (number == 1)
        {
            minigame = new MinigameTwo();
        }
        else
        {
            minigame = new MinigameThree();
        } 
    }
}
```

The minigame is always loaded using a "new" instance of an object, but there is never any form of deletion when the minigame is completed and the player chooses another one. Does C# expect me to do something like the following or is it safe for me to keep using "new" over and over again without finding a way to delete the variable (i.e. the same code as below, minus the delete commands)?

```
minigame = new MinigameOne();

//Do something with the minigame

delete minigame; //I don't think this command exists in C#, but is there an equivalent?
minigame = new MinigameTwo();

//Do something again

delete minigame;
minigame = new MinigameThree();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once all references to an object are removed, it becomes eligible for garbage collection. By overwriting the reference held in `minigame`, you're removing the reference to the previous minigame object. As long as there are no other references to it, some time later the garbage collector will gobble it up.

I suggest that you take a read of ["The fundamentals of garbage collection"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx) for a better understanding of how objects reach the end of their lifetime.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to mention calling `Dispose` if the object implements `IDisposable`, as there might be unmanaged ressources to be disposed.

Comment: I find it highly unlikely that OP is messing with unmanaged code and feel that adding this level of detail would be distracting.

Comment: @spender while the OP doesn't "mess" with unmanaged code him/herself, it's more than likely than XNA does, which is one of the probable reason for `Game` to implement `IDisposable`. I would certainly recommend that either an explicit call to `Dispose()` be made, or a `using` statement be used.

Comment: Actually the majority of XNA developers _will_ be using unmanaged code even if they are not aware.  e.g. `SpriteBatch`; `Texture` which are `IDisposable`. Such resources need to be released during `Game.UnloadContent()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about XNA specifically, but I'm thinking it must allocate some resources that need to be released, or you risk running out of them after a while (file handle, brushes, what have you).

While the .NET Garbage Collector (GC) will generally do a good job at managing memory, it will not release unmanaged resources such as the ones above.

You should make sure that you follow proper XNA best practices (whatever they are).

I'm thinking that a [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/yh598w02.aspx) block should be enough to Dispose of your `Game` object since Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game implements IDisposable.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No, .Net will to it for you.

Once you create new object and assign it to minigame variable it becomes eligible to garbage collector (since no one reference it anymore). After some time GC will look throgh heap and delete object with no referencies to it.